# laravel installation on shared hosting with composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to learn Laravel and follow the instructions in their [tutorial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4) to install the framework on my shared hosting. I've disabled the secure-http option in composer but it still won't download the framework.

Called:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

Response:

```
Changed current directory to /home/sledzko/.composer
Warning: Accessing packagist.org over http which is an insecure protocol.

[LogicException]                                                              
Composer repositories that have providers can not load the complete list of packages, use getProviderNames instead.
```

What can I do to download the framework using composer?

Comment: Why don't you use the create-project instead of installer?

Comment: I've got that problem myself and did some searching. It seems that most common issue that create this problem is troubled internet connection. You may want to read [this github discussion](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1688) and [this one](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5550)

Comment: Why don't you ask you shared hosting company. Maybe they have a solution or  another way to install Laravel.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu create-project doesn't work as well. Displays the same error

Comment: What is your composer version? Please run `composer --version`

Answer (score 3):

Most of the shared hosting is not supported terminal/command access, that why it is not possible to install Laravel using composer on shared hosting.

But there is a way to use Laravel in shared hosting, you can install/setup Laravel project on a local machine and after that upload project (all directory structure and files) on your shared hosting. Only need to adjust public directory and bootstrap path in the index.php file.

Upload all files is in public folder in your shared hosting www/public_html folder, and all other folder structure in the separate folder. After that go to your index.php file in www/public_html folder and update below two linew with your path laravel folder path.

require **DIR**.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once **DIR**.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

Comment: I have SSH access and I'm currently using all those commands through SSH so that that's not an issue. I'll try the local installation, but I was hoping to install Laravel globally with composer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install package locally using Composer. The package folder will be created in the `vendor` path.
2. Copy `vendor/packagename` folder and paste it into your host's `vendor` path.
3. Replace your host `vendor/composer` folder with your local `vendor/composer` folder.
4. Replace your host `composer.json` with your local `composer.json`

Answer (score 1):

please try:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist YOUR_PROJECT_NAME
```

This will help you to download the stable version on your machine!

Comment: This command results in error: `[LogicException]                                                              
  Composer repositories that have providers can not load the complete list of packages, use getProviderNames instead.`

Comment: Oh, sorry @Ajin, I have written false statements. Exactly is: composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel YOUR_PROJECT_NAME

 Hope can help you!

Answer (score -2):

If you use [SiteGround](https://www.siteground.com/) you will be a lucky man, just must request access do ssh (over cpanel), and then run your `composer` command on terminal.

[SiteGround](https://www.siteground.com/) servers already have composer globally installed.

BUT... you you want to do it on hard way, access you shell on Siteground and run:

```
 wget https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar -O ${HOME}/composer.phar
 echo "alias composer=\"/usr/local/php72/bin/php-cli ${HOME}/composer.phar \"" >> ${HOME}/.bashrc
 source ${HOME}/.bashrc
 composer --version
```

Just pay attention on php72 version, it's uses PHP 7.2. If you want or need another one do a `ls /usr/local/` to see all versions.

Comment: Really sorry for the downvotes here, they are because of the post being discussed on meta. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371788/4099593. I am probably to blame for that.